# How to Install vim-full in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, vim

I cannot find it in `apt-get`. I need `vimdiff`.

---

How can you install **vim-full** in *Ubuntu 16.04*?

Comment: try *app-get update* first and then try *app-get install vim*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**vimdiff** tool is under package vim. You should install vim using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Then you can use the **vimdiff** as:

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

Comment: thank you. I used diff a lot and i didn't know that a better vimdiff is available.

Answer (score 3):

A number of Vim packages are available in the default repositories which have been compiled with different feature-sets.  You can search to see which ones are available using:

```
apt-cache -n search vim
```

A number of packages provide a version of Vim that has been compiled with the “full” set of Vim features:

- If you only want Vim for command-line use, you can install the `vim-nox` package (it installs the `vim-common` package as a dependency).
- If using a GNOME-based desktop environment, install `vim-gnome` (it executable has been compiled with dependencies on GNOME libraries such as `libgnome2`, `libbonoboui2`).
- If using another desktop environment, `vim-gtk` provides a GTK2 GUI; its only dependency is `vim-gui-common` (as a Lubuntu user, that’s what I use).

Comment: I think I installed `vim-gtk` but it does not have `vimdiff`. Vim-full existed before and I am searching its corresponding thing.

Comment: @Masi What's the output of `update-alternatives --display vimdiff` ?

Comment: I already installed rajthakur's command which works.

Answer (score 3):

[How to install the latest Vim on Ubuntu 16.04](https://gitlab.com/bogdanvlviv/posts/-/issues/8), summary reproduced here:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt update

sudo apt install -y git

sudo apt install -y build-essential

rm -fr /tmp/vim

git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git /tmp/vim

make -C /tmp/vim

sudo make install -C /tmp/vim

rm -fr /tmp/vim
```

Comment: Please, no link-only answers, otherwise it is a comment. I put there the summary.